# DB Query in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to perform a database search in an application, however, I have been unable to get the search to work properly.

In the index page I have the option to search or display all items in the database, however the `return all` always seems to be called, instead of the search.  If someone searches, I would like to only display the searched for item when the search is completed.

I am, however, running into some issues.

articles_controller.rb:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:id]
      fun = Article.find_by(title: params[:id].search)
    else
      @articles = Article.all
    end
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:search])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text))

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

article.rb:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }

    def self.search(search)
      if :search
        Article.where('tite LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
      else
        Article.all
      end
    end

end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Listing articles</h1>

<%= link_to 'New article', new_article_path %> 

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>


  <%= form_tag articles_path, :method => 'get' do %>
     <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :title => nil %>
     </p>
 <% end %>

</table>
```

Backend DB:

```
Started GET "/articles?search=asdfa&commit=Search&utf8=%E2%9C%93" for ::1 at 2016-03-14 15:01:12 -0400
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"search"=>"asdfa", "commit"=>"Search", "utf8"=>"✓"}
  Article Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"
  Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 18.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

The latest error/incorrect call is:

```
Started GET "/assets/application.self-3b8dabdc891efe46b9a144b400ad69e37d7e5876bdc39dee783419a69d7ca819.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2016-03-14 15:39:25 -0400


Started GET "/articles?search=asdfa&commit=Search&utf8=%E2%9C%93" for ::1 at 2016-03-14 15:39:40 -0400
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"search"=>"asdfa", "commit"=>"Search", "utf8"=>"✓"}
  Article Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"
  Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 17.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? How can I fix/make this work?

Comment: When asking it helps to come up with a more definitive title, not something generic and nondescript. The title is what grabs the attention of those who you wish to have help you, so accuracy is good.

Answer (score 3):

You've defined `search` method in your model, but you are not using in it in your controller:

```
def index
  @articles = Article.search params[:search]
end
```

In your model, you have some logic errors (symbol `:search` instead of `search` variable, *tite* instead of `title` ):

```
def self.search search
  search.present? ? where('title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%") : all
end
```

Comment: still get the following

`Started GET "/articles?search=asdfa&commit=Search&utf8=%E2%9C%93" for ::1 at 2016-03-14 15:30:01 -0400
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"search"=>"asdfa", "commit"=>"Search", "utf8"=>"✓"}
  Article Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"
  Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 17.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)`

Comment: we have introduced a new error unfortunately, I will post in main body to maintain formatting.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you have:

```
def index
    if params[:id]
      fun = Article.find_by(title: params[:id].search)
    else
      @articles = Article.all
    end
end
```

but you are definitely not passing any id to the controller via the form.

For example, you can change the condition to:

```
if params[:search]
```

and then find by:

```
Article.find_by(title: params[:search])
```